# How to achieve drawing an border for a set of cells in javafx table view

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a sample table. 
I need to show a border for a set of table cells based on the input as shown in the following picture :
[image]
The key is, the border location is dynamic and it based on the input to the table. My table data can be large and it can hold 25 columns and 500 rows. The information i have is the row index and column index of the start cell and the end cell.

I cannot use `updateItem()` function as `updateItem()` will not be called for cells which is not shown in the `tableview`. I am unable to access the `tablecell` object after the table is loaded. 
 Is there a way to dynamically `setStyle` to the tableCells after the tableview is loaded ?

Comment: Without accessing the cells directly, there's no way (that I know of) to do this. Also, you can't use `updateItem()` because it wouldn't affect items that aren't shown? What is the point of drawing a border that can't be seen anyway?

Comment: The border shows whether the complete data is A4 proportionate. i.e the width/length = 0.707. If the ratio is not met, the user is allowed to move the cell value to empty cells and adjust the height. So after adjusting, the user will recalculate whether A4 is met or not. So the border is used to show how much area is coming under the A4.

Comment: I see. I suggest you add a [mcve] to your question to show what you've done so far. How are the calculations done, etc.

Comment: Hello, setting the style is done in the updateItem as the cell is rendered.  JavaFX only uses the cells that are visible on screen and then swaps out the data, so it doesn't matter how many rows there are, as the cell becomes visible or the data is changed (reused), update item will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments which gave a different insight.
I solved the issue like this:
Calculated the left top indexes and right bottom indexes for which I need to draw the border, and used those values in the `updateItem()` method of table cell like this:

```java
if(tableCol.getTableView() != null) {
    A4CalculationIndexValues a4CalculationIndexValues = A4Calculation.A4LayoutDetails.get(tableCol.getTableView().getId());
    if(a4CalculationIndexValues != null) {
        Integer startRow = a4CalculationIndexValues.startRowColumnIndex.getRow();
        Integer startColumn = a4CalculationIndexValues.startRowColumnIndex.getColumn();
        Integer endColumn = a4CalculationIndexValues.endRowColumnIndex.getColumn();
        Integer endRow = a4CalculationIndexValues.endRowColumnIndex.getRow();

        if (getIndex() == startRow &&  columnIndex >= startColumn && columnIndex <= endColumn) {
            if (getStyle().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1 2 3 4; -fx-border-color: red white white white");
        }
        if (getIndex() >= startRow && getIndex() <= endRow && columnIndex == startColumn) {
            if (getStyle().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1 2 3 4; -fx-border-color: white white white red");
        }
        if (getIndex() == endRow && columnIndex >= startColumn && columnIndex <= endColumn) {
            if (getStyle().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1 2 3 4; -fx-border-color: white white red white");
        }
        if (getIndex() >= startRow && getIndex() <= endRow && columnIndex == endColumn) {
            if (getStyle().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1 2 3 4; -fx-border-color: white red white white");
        }
    }
}
```